# Spring scheduled multiple running with Tomcat multiple context

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have to run one web application in two different paths. I created two different contexts with different paths in one host.

Everything working fine but when I have two contexts, my Spring scheduled (annotation driven) running twice. I suspect it is standard behaviour - there are two running containers with two parallel applications.

Is there any way to create something like a "virtual context" or "context alias"? Or anything else solution to create more than one path for one application?

Comment: Why do you want to have two instances of the same application in the same tomcat controller ? Would it be enough to map the application to 2 different servlet paths ?

Comment: Because I have two domains. First domain, e.g. "domain1.com" working on "/" path and second domain e.g. "domain2.com" working with path "/app" like: "domain2.com/app". Maybe there is a another solution for this case?

Comment: Could it be an option to have an Apache reverse proxy to manage the external URLs (and cache static content), and one tomcat hosting the application ? It is a current architecture on large datacenters ...